# ruby on rails multiple checkbox params

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, parameters

I have an application in which multiple checkboxes to be selected, so how to provide the name as an array in checkbox tag so that I can retrieve it in my params in controller.
I am actually quite confused in my checkbox params, especially for multiple checkboxes.
can I give it any random name in checkbox name = "any name " so that i can access it in my params in controller
Please heed my query, I can't even find an appropriate article for the same

Thanks in advance

I named it as hi[] array, 'hi' random word or should I have to follow some convention

```
<input type="checkbox" name= "hi[]" value="" class="form-select form-control" id="clients"
                           onchange="this.value=this.checked;"  style="display: inline-block;width: 20px;" />
```

Comment: Your question is not cleared. What you need actually?  Checkbox  form helper or checkbox value from parameter or checkbox name from parameter

Comment: i need to know about checkbox name from parameter, and how to name them when we have multiple checkboxes, if we have name then we can easily retrieve its value from params .                                                                           like i named it hi[ ], is it correct ? can i put any random name and use that name in  my params in controller

Comment: Yes it is correct for checkbox array

Comment: Then how will I retrieve all the values in Params in controller ... what I mean by values is true for check boxes which are checked , like params[:hi][]

Answer (score 0):

If your query looks like this

```
www.example.com/query?foo[]=bar&hi[]=hey
```

Then checkbox will look like below for creating checkbox with value and name from parameters

```
<% unless params[:foo].blank? %>
    <%= check_box_tag("foo[]", "#{params[:foo]}", checked: true) %> <%= params[:foo] %>
<% end %>

<% unless params[:hi].blank? %>
    <%= check_box_tag("hi[]", "#{params[:hi]}", checked: true) %> <%= params[:hi] %>
<% end %>
```

HTML checkbox looks like below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" id="foo_" value="bar" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="hi[]" id="hi_" value="hey" checked="checked">
```

Let me know what you expect this?

Comment: I have to send client id to my params, for which check box is selected I have to associate a client id too so that I could know those clients were selected via check box in my modal form .i have client id with me but how to associate it with my check box , what about hidden in HTML form can I send it via hidden value